# Can I import a custom Google Map into iOS MapKit?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, dictionary, mapkit, customizing

Let's say I have a custom fictional map create with Google maps. It is not a real place, but a custom one. Kind of like a map of the lord of the rings location, mordor or something. Working as a Google map on browser, with pins, custom image and all. Is there a way to import this to iOS MapKit to show in my own iOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to export the google map in KML format and then use a library to parse the KML data and view it in a MKMapView.

This seems to be useful: http://kmlframework.com

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. Might take some time, as I'm working on multiple assignments atm, but I will get back here and mark as answer if it works when I'm done. If anyone else have any other ideas, please let me know.

Comment: I never got to try this out. We went with another custom solution, but I'll mark as answer because the kmlFramework was to huge help in this matter, thank you.